# Using oData queries with MVC 3 Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, odata

Is it possible to use oData queries with MVC 3 Actions if I return a Queryable? Like so:

```
public JsonResult GetComplaints()
{
    var complaints = db.Complaints.AsQueryable();
    return Json(complaints, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or

```
public IQueryable<Complaint> GetComplaints()
{
    return db.Complaints.AsQueryable();
}
```

If I call it like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetComplaints")?$filter=startswith(CompanyName, \'123\')',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your second example with the `IQueryable<Complaint>` can work, but only if you are using Web API and the method is inside an `ApiController`. Regular MVC controllers don't support odata queries out of the box.

Comment: Thought as much, guess I'll need to install web api in my MVC 3 project then. Thanks

Comment: I've installed Web API but I can't use the `[Queryable]` attribute?

Comment: AFAIK Odata is still in preview and you need a [separate nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData)

Comment: Thanks, that did it, if you want to create an answer I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example action with the `IQueryable<Complaint>` can function as an OData endpoint, but only if you are using Web API and the method is inside an `ApiController`.

Regular MVC controllers don't support odata queries out of the box.

You can start learning about the OData support in Web.API [from this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx)

OData can be installed as a [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData):

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
```